# Send keystrokes to vnc server without GUI

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, vnc

I want to make a program that connects to a VNC server and then sends a sequence of key presses, then disconnects. And all without ever showing a GUI.

Example use:

```
vnckeysender SERVER KEYPRESSES
```

Where SERVER would be something like "10.0.0.1" and KEYPRESSES would be something like "The quick brown fox".

I would like to write it in python, but I am not sure where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a command line utility written in python called [vncdotool](https://github.com/sibson/vncdotool). It can also be used as a library and imported into existing python scripts to connect and send keyboard and mouse input to a VNC server.